# How do you run a server with chrooted Ubuntu on the HP TouchPad?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, chroot

The problem: servers appear to be broken inside my Ubuntu chroot. No matter what kind of server I try to run, they all seem unresponsive (VLC server won't respond to client, [mkRemote](http://devbury.com/) doesn't move the cursor, Apache gives an error about binding to port 80 and won't start, etc.).

If I'm not mistaken, what should normally happen inside a chroot is that all ports are shared between the chroot and the host, so if another machine tries to hit the host at port 80, it will still see the chrooted Web server. However, here, that isn't what's happening.

When I run netstat from the chroot, every single process lists a foreign address of 0.0.0.0:*, meaning that the only machine which can act as a client is the local host. This is clearly incorrect and abnormal behaviour, as any process on my primary machine meant to be publicly visible lists a foreign address of :::* (which I assume means that any client can see it from any port).
*Edit: Disregard that; apparently the foreign address only distinguishes between whether it's listening for IPv4 or IPv6 connections, so it doesn't seem relevant here.*

So far, Googling has returned nothing of value, and I'm basically stumped. Any ideas? Could it just be some setting which one of the chroot patch devs enabled by default, or does it seem like a more complicated issue?

More context: http://rootzwiki.com/topic/14682-webos-servers-inside-chrooted-ubuntu/

Comment: Possibly relevant information:
* http://buu700.com/tpbind
* http://buu700.com/tpnetstat
* http://buu700.com/tpnmap

Comment: * http://buu700.com/tpiptables0
* http://buu700.com/tpiptables1
* http://buu700.com/tpiptables2
* http://buu700.com/tptcpdump

Comment: Bump. Did you try out my solution?

Comment: Oh, hey, sorry about that; I meant to update this three months ago and completely forgot (I actually only noticed your response now because I opened a SuperUser result from Google and saw the notification bar). I did actually end up (in January) doing pretty much exactly what you wrote, so thanks for the awesome answer! (I'd upvote it too, but my reputation isn't high enough. :/)

Comment: Aside: The WiFi mouse idea apparently sucks. It's unusably laggy, and not worth trying at all. However, CM9 on the TouchPad is incredibly stable and works brilliantly with a cheap BlueTooth mouse (must-have apps, beyond a chroot, for desktop replacement: DroidEdit Pro, Better Terminal Pro, Dolphin Browser HD).

Comment: I have CM9 and chrooted Ubuntu on my TouchPad. I use a Bluetooth keyboard which works quite well, though I haven't tried a mouse yet. I really enjoy having a full desktop environment on a competent 10" tablet that cost me less than my iPod Touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I found this question while searching the Internet for an answer, and I just discovered a solution! I was trying to get a Ruby on Rails WEBrick server running on my chrooted Ubuntu on my TouchPad. I surprisingly got all my gems installed correctly, and I started up the rails server. I went to `localhost:3000` in my browser on my TouchPad, and it loaded up my project just fine. However, when I tried to navigate to my TouchPad's server on my desktop by visiting `192.168.x.x:3000`, the request timed out. I knew that this had to be a firewall issue, but when checking in my chrooted Ubuntu, I realized that the firewall was disabled, and iptables wasn't even installed. I began thinking, and came up with a theory that WebOS was blocking the communication on all the ports. I scanned the ports with a network scanner on my computer, and nothing was open. It would ping-pong, but no port access. After some more searching, I found that the TouchPad uses iptables within WebOS. An easy way to access the underlying Linux behind WebOS is to use XTerm (you probably installed it along with Xecutah and XServer from Preware). Just start Xecutah, and click Start XTerm. I typed these commands to allow all access on all ports for WebOs, which in turn gives all port access to chrooted Ubuntu:

`sudo iptables-save > /firewall.rules`

`iptables -X`

`iptables -t nat -F`

`iptables -t nat -X`

`iptables -t mangle -F`

`iptables -t mangle -X`

`iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT`

`iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT`

`iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT`

`iptables -F`

Don't worry if `iptables -X` gives you a link error. If, after you're done testing your server, you'd like to restore the firewall in WebOS, then just run this command:

`iptables-restore < /firewall.rules`

This is everything that got my server working on chrooted Ubuntu. The same should work for you.